# How can I get the whole execution log of stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that how many times it was executed from execution_count in sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats.But how these values are Calculated? Is there any way to know how these values get calculated? I want whole log when the stored procedure was first time executed to till last_execution_time logs.

Answer (score 1):

> But how these values are Calculated? Is there any way to know how
>   these values get calculated?

Answer to this can be refer from MSDN stating below

```
sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
```

> Returns aggregate performance statistics for cached stored procedures.
>   The view returns one row for each cached stored procedure plan, and
>   the lifetime of the row is as long as the stored procedure remains
>   cached. When a stored procedure is removed from the cache, the
>   corresponding row is eliminated from this view. At that time, a
>   Performance Statistics SQL trace event is raised similar to
>   sys.dm_exec_query_stats

You can run something like below code to collect the data from this dmv as per the load to analyse the usage of resources during the execution of that SP:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN database_id = 32767 then 'Resource' ELSE DB_NAME(database_id)END AS DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id,database_id) AS [SCHEMA_NAME] 
      ,OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id)AS [OBJECT_NAME]
      ,cached_time
      ,last_execution_time
      ,execution_count
      ,total_worker_time / execution_count AS AVG_CPU
      ,total_elapsed_time / execution_count AS AVG_ELAPSED
      ,total_logical_reads / execution_count AS AVG_LOGICAL_READS
      ,total_logical_writes / execution_count AS AVG_LOGICAL_WRITES
      ,total_physical_reads  / execution_count AS AVG_PHYSICAL_READS
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats 
ORDER BY AVG_LOGICAL_READS DESC
```

You can modify the query above and gather the data to collect the metrics for the SP by scheduling it via SQL agent job. After a certain interval you will have sufficient data to make analysis. An example of such is illustrated [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI KASQLDBA , that `execution_count` should be calculated when the sp get executed . So I want that executed time log . for eg. `execution_count` =10 means the sp get executed 10 times(the same plan get executed 10 times), where this info get stored?

Comment: The information is *not* stored.  It is cached *in memory* as long as the stored proc remains in the procedure cache.  On a lightly used system, this may be since the first time the proc was ran after the last time the server was restarted.  As @KASQLDBA said, you'll need to capture the information using a SQL Server Agent Job scheduled to run as often as needed.